# Getting location of button in grid from Mousehover (C# VS)

Tags: c#, arrays, button, multidimensional-array, mousehover

in school I'm currently working on a game of battleships for AP Comp Sci and I have been trying to get it so that during the ship placing stage a picturebox (a ship) changes location to that of whichever button the mouse happens to be hovering over. This is supposed to act like a ghost icon for where you would be placing the ship. The buttons are in an array as they are made in a grid using a 2D forloop.

I couldn't figure out how to make MouseHover work with getting a buttons location from an array of buttons. This is mostly because I don't know how to give the x y values for the buttons location in the array to the MouseHover method.

I tried using a timer that checked each button in the array for whether it had focus and it changed the location of the picturebox to that button successfully:

```
private void MouseXYCheckTimer_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
            {
                if (b[x, y].Focused)
                {
                    ShipImage1.Location = b[x, y].Location;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

however this required clicking the button to give it focus (thus placing the ship), defeating the purpose.

I've looked quite extensively at different posts here on MouseHover and I still cant get it to work for my problem, help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are built in events for handling MouseEnter

```
// Wire up the MouseEnter event when creating your buttons
button.MouseEnter += button_MouseEnter;

// Method that gets called
private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    ShipImage1.Location = button.Location;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did end up using this and its working beautifully! I feel stupid for it but it didn't hit me until I actually got it working that the picturebox actually blocks you from clicking on any of the buttons. Is there any way that I could make it so you can click through the picturebox for the button to detect a click? or should i scrap the idea. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and assuming you are using Winforms, you just need to subscribe your picture position logic to the `MouseMove` event of each one of your buttons. So try the following:

Define this method in your class:

```
private void button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ShipImage1.Location = e.Location;
}
```

Then in the logic responsible for creating the instance of each button stored into your `b` array, subscribe that method to the `MouseMove` event:

```
...
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
    {
        var myButton = new Button();

        myButton.MouseMove += button_MouseMove;

        // More awesome stuff around myButton...

        b[x, y] = myButton;
    }
}
...
```

Also if needed, you can get the current screen mouse coordinates from the `Form.MousePosition` static property.

Good luck!

**EDIT**
Or use instead the `MouseEnter` event as indicated by @Jerry in the other answer, that should work better.

Comment: Thank you, I did end up using the MouseEnter method and its working beautifully! I feel stupid for it but it didn't hit me until I actually got it working that the picturebox actually blocks you from clicking on any of the buttons. Is there any way that I could make it so you can click through the picturebox for the button to detect a click? or should i scrap the idea. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Well, there are different ways of solving that... a quick way could be, if you are using @jerry logic, in the `button_MouseEnter` method set `ShipImage1.Tag = button;`, then subscribe to the `Click` event of `ShipImage1` and there do `((Button)ShipImage1.Tag)?.PerformClick();`. This is quite dirty but should work.